# using aggregation on mongo field of type Map where values are an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection storing person details. A person can have name along with contact information. The contact information is a map with values being an array. Sample JSON structure is as below

```
[
  {
    id: 'objectId1',
    name: 'Name1',
    contactInfo: {
      Email: [
        'first@email',
        'second@email'
      ],
      phone: [
        123456
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I need to create a view which contains the information in the below format

```
[
  {
    name: 'Name1',
    email: 'first@email'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name1',
    email: 'second@email'
  },
  {
    name: 'Name1',
    phone: 123456
  }
]
```

There are certain additional criteria

1. the contactInfo field can be empty map
2. the contactInfo field may not have same number of keys (for example only contact of type phone is present)
3. the values are of type array in the map so there can be more than one element. It is also possible that the value field is blank
4. The map can be blank so this record is also a possibility

> ```
> {
>     id: "objectId1",
>     name: "Name3",
>     contactInfo: {}
>   }
> ```

and in this case the output will have the record as

> {
> name: 'Name3'
> }

How do I go about writing the query? I am trying to use the aggregation function $objectToArray but not sure how to handle the additional conditions of value being an array.

Edit1 -
I also need the output as

```
{
  name: 'Name1',
  contactType: 'email',
  contactInfo: 'first@email'
}
```

I tried to modify the query but it is not working as k and v is standard there so looks like some kind of unwind is required on the final projection but not able to make the query work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$objectToArray` inside a `$reduce` in order to flatten the map of arrays to a flat array of objects with a single value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      contactInfo: {$reduce: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$contactInfo"},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$map: {
                  input: "$$this.v",
                  as: "item",
                  in: {k: "$$this.k", v: "$$item"}
              }}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: {
      path: "$contactInfo",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }},
  {$project: {
      contactInfo: [
        {$ifNull: [
            "$contactInfo",
            {k: "name", v: "$name"}
        ]},
        {k: "name", v: "$name"}
      ]
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$contactInfo"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uzmwXncHMvs)

Comment: thanks this is working. However I forgot to mention an additional condition  that the map may not have any keys at all. As an example the below record (I edited my question)                                                  {
    id: "objectId1",
    name: "Name3",
    contactInfo: {}
  }

Comment: My solution still works on this case: https://mongoplayground.net/p/o3XjrP4t7Sc

Comment: I missed the fact that such records should be included in the output..

Comment: if I want the output record as {
    name: 'Name1',
 contactType:'email',
    contactDetails: 'first@email'
  } whereever contactInfo is not empty, what kind of changes is required.. I tried to change the query but its not working since k and v are standard

Comment: That is a simple case: https://mongoplayground.net/p/O_yoLtbWP4d

Comment: when we remove the emails and phone number from a record, the whole record gets removed (the expectation is that only id and name field should remain in the record). To me it looks like a Mongo issue as the query seems correct. Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to mongodb playground with such example?

Comment: please ignore this as of now.. to me it seems to be some different issue.. will ping back